# how can I parse data to Json and return to another method using Createdataction?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a post method to add a new category and save it to the database. and I want to return CreateAtAction to another getmethod.but as I execute the code the data saves in the database with 200 success.

When I try to use Swagger UI though I get "Can not parse json data" and this post method does not move to another get method.

[image]

> CategoryController.cs

```
[HttpPost]        
public async Task<IActionResult> AddCategory([FromBody] Category category)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    _categoryRepository.Add(category);
    await Task.Run(() => _categoryRepository.SaveChanges());
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetCategoryById) , new { id = category.Id }, category);
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]        
public IActionResult GetCategoryById([FromRoute]long id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    //var category = await _context.Category.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.ParentId == id);
    var ListCategories =  _categoryRepository.GetById(id);
    if (ListCategories == null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(ListCategories);
}
```

Comment: The error complains about the string you sent to JSON. It's not produced by the code you posted. It's clear too - that string is an invalid JSON string. Most likely there's an unescaped double quote in there. Since you *didn't* post the actual code, just a screenshot, it's not possible to tell you what it is. Images can't be compiled or edited.

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes inside the string to avoid escaping and errors